# Compaq DL360 PCI Memory controller

Tags: hp-proliant, drivers, hp

I have a Compaq DL360 with two P3/933 Mhz CPUs and 1152 MB RAM running Windows 2003. Device manager shows a yellow question mark over the PCI Memory Controller. I understand that device to be the remote access PCI card, although it seems to be working fine. Do I need to install a specific driver for it? Where could I find that specific driver?

Comment: Have you visted the HP site to download the current driver set?

Answer (score 2):

A Compaq/HP DL360 G1. Older server, circa 1999-2001. The [complete driver set](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=261261&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D261261%257CprodSeriesId%253D254886%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for that model is available [here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=261261&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D261261%257CprodSeriesId%253D254886%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

You may want to consider installing the entire [Proliant Support Pack](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=261261&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Dlang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D254886%257CprodNameId%253D261261%257CswEnvOID%253D1005%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-0d468f8119764a869130bef9a1%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) to get the full set of drivers for that model.

Comment: I found the required files on the HP website. **Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

This is for the G5 variant of the DL360 [DL360 Drivers](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DriverDownload.jsp?prodNameId=3288144&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=135&prodClassId=-1&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=1121486)